# Proactively sharing time-sensitive feedback with manager?

Tags: performance-reviews, feedback, onboarding

My company is in the middle of its annual performance review cycle. As a part of that, I was asked to provide feedback to my manager via a web portal. One of the questions asks about a "growth opportunity" for the manager.

My response to this question (in so many words) is that the manager needs to be better about bringing new members onto the team. In short, people will join the team then they won't actually be given work for a month or two. I saw this happen to me and to another new colleague (who was also puzzled by it). There isn't a shortage of work. I just think that the manager doesn't make an effort to find new, small items that a new member could take on that would help them to become acquainted with the code base.

*We have a new team member joining on Monday.* So my feedback is rather relevant here.

**My question, then, is:** *should I let my manager know about this feedback today?* If so, should I do it over messenger/slack or ask for a quick meeting (I'm remote)?

Some additional context that may be helpful:

- I have no qualms about providing this feedback. I think that my manager can take this in stride. That being said, they don't tend to ask for feedback from me proactively outside of formal review periods.
- Although the performance reviews have names removed from them, I expect that my manager will be able to tell that I provided the feedback. There aren't too many people on the team and I have a somewhat distinctive writing style.
- If I don't tell them the feedback right now, they probably won't see it for a few weeks at the earliest.
- This is a software engineering team.

Comment: Welcome to The Workplace, plase take the [tour] and read the [help/dont-ask] to familiarize yourself with the site. I must say that usually "should I" questions are off-topic (as it's basically your choice, and not ours)... however, reading through it I see an answer and will post it shortly

Comment: The manager may have little control over start dates.

Comment: Whatever you choose to do, I would suggest phrasing it as a "suggestion" and not "feedback".  Most people will have no problems being given suggestions at any time, for pretty much any reason.

Comment: I would tread very carefully, a phrase I use on this stack exchange a lot!

Answer (score 5):

I know this feels urgent, since someone is about to start, but let's try a thought experiment. You go to your manager and say something like this:

> I was doing my anonymous review and one of the questions caused a thought to crystallize for me for the first time. I put it in the review, but I actually think it's super urgent you know my thoughts on this **right now**. When people start here they don't have much to do for the first month, and this is unpleasant for them. I'm guessing it never occurred to you that people would like to do work right away. It would be great if, for the person starting Monday, you came up with some little tasks for them so they feel more comfortable.

Now let's further imagine that your boss was genuinely unaware that people feel  uncomfortable having no tasks, so this is a real lightbulb moment and your boss is immediately convinced! It will be Wednesday, and the boss will have stuff planned for the next few days. Do you think they will drop everything to give this person tasks? Do you think they will go to other people and tell them to change their plans in order to ensure a new way of onboarding new people?

I don't. Not even if the boss is transformed on the spot and agrees you're completely right. The thing is, changing how onboarding is done takes time. While some people might be frustrated not having things to do, others appreciate some low pressure time to learn their way around. And nobody likes having to interrupt what they had planned to do in order to support the new person who wants to feel that they are doing meaningful work on day 1 instead of sitting and reading all the stuff they can read without using up other people's time. So there won't be universal support for "give them more tasks." And giving tasks is a non-trivial effort that often relies on knowing what the new person knows, which you won't know until they arrive. Maybe until they perform their first few very small tasks.

**That doesn't mean your boss is doing it right**: there's low-pressure and there's "whatever just sit at your desk and leave the rest of us alone". But it does mean that a simple "by Jove you're right! I better get started finding tasks for the new person!" is not going to happen even if you bypass the review process to deliver your urgent feedback out of band. It's not actually that urgent. It can't be acted on as quickly as you think it can. If anything, I like the timing that the boss will get this info right after a new person started who definitely didn't provide the feedback. They can sit and think about how this new person was onboarded, and reflect on that or even ask the new person about it.

Answer (score 2):

> My company is in the middle of its annual performance review cycle. As a part of that, I was asked to provide feedback to my manager via a web portal.
>
> [...] should I let my manager know about this feedback today?

**If your company already has an established procedure and web portal dedicated to give feedback and performance review, then I suggest you stick to that**. You say feedback is anonymized (good call IMHO), and most likely parsed and presented nicely along other feedback... why would you want to de-anonymize yours? or why should your feedback be treated differently that the one others gave?

Skipping this process, or doing it twice actually, and bringing (unsolicited and redundant) feedback to your manager may not be the best way to go. It may convey the message *"I already gave feedback on the official and established portal, but I don't trust that's enough for you to oblige to/acknowledge it"*

Addressing your specific points/worries:

> I have no qualms about providing this feedback. I think that my manager can take this in stride. That being said, they don't tend to ask for feedback from me proactively outside of formal review periods.

Then let your manager take the feedback on the official way. The last sentence gives weight to the "unsolicited" part I mentioned before.

> Although the performance reviews are anonymous, I expect that my manager will be able to tell that I provided the feedback. There aren't too many people on the team and I have a somewhat distinctive writing style.

Contradiction. Reviews are anonymized you say, so there will be no way for anyone to know who gave what feedback (as I said, all feedback is processed, anonymized, etc. it's not like they paste your comment exactly as you wrote it). If they do paste it exactly like that, then I fear it's not anonymized.

> If I don't tell them the feedback right now, they probably won't see it for a few weeks at the earliest

I think this is a non-issue, and again skipping protocols and processes (what is the urgency of *your* feedback compared to the others?). Making your manager aware of *your* feedback now will not change the weight or importance of your feedback.

Comment: I have updated my phrasing re:”anonymous.” Names are simply removed. Thank you for your detailed response otherwise.

Comment: The anonymisation is mostly formal here. The  manager doesn't officially get any names on which review came from whom but in practice they can guess quite accurately for any review longer than two or three words.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah you are worrying too much about your manager's job. Any feedback like this will likely be taken as a criticism. If it's a company-wide thing then you could say "Company-wide we could do on-boarding of new staff better by giving them relevant tasks early to speed up productivity"

Anything more and your manager will be thinking that you have too much time on your hands and give you more work to do...